# Extract Tables from an Iframe - Anbima Using python + selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, iframe

Sup, I'm trying to extract some data tables from an website (https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/curvas-de-juros-fechamento.htm), but as we can see the data is inside an Iframe. It took me a while, since I'm not an expert to webscraping data, to click in the button "Consultar" to get in the page that I want. Basically, i't loads the data (4 tables) that inside an Iframe too.

The problem it's I still don't have any successful attempt to get the tables, maybe it's because of the Iframe.

For an example, I tried to use xpath i the first table without sucess.

drive.find_elemnt_by_xpath(//*[@id="Parametros"]/table).text

Here's the code to reach the page that i mentioned:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import re
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as expectedCondition
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#----------------------- INICIALIZAÇÃO DO SCRAPING -----------------------------#
want_to_scrape = True
if want_to_scrape:
    options = Options()
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\......\\chromedriver.exe",options=options)
   
    now = time.time()
    dataset_list = []
    
    url = 'https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/curvas-de-juros-fechamento.htm'
    driver.get(url)
    

    #element  = driver.find_element_by_class_name('full')
    #driver.switch_to.frame(element)

    driver.switch_to.frame(0)
    
    element = driver.find_elements_by_name('Consultar')
    element[0].click()
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.accept()
        print("alert accepted")
    except:
        print("no alert")
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.switch_to.frame(0)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `driver.switch_to.frame(0)` line with this:

```
# Get the iframe element - note, may need to use more specialized selector here
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

That will get your driver into the frame context so you can fetch the tables. You may need to use a different selector to get the `iframe` element. If you post the `iframe` HTML here, I can help you write a selector.

Comment: I already got how to select the iframe..in both cases, there's only one frame per page. Now i only need to get the data from the tables, but it's not working.

Comment: Could you copy the full page source? I can see the `<table>` element in the screenshot you provided, but there might be other elements causing issues, such as nested `iframe`. You can create a gist, or a google doc, where you can share the full page source. https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-gists

Comment: Here's the source html from the frame and the source code from the page:

- https://gist.github.com/ANDPPOLI/423608d7e2f5e9e3536181eb38efefac



- https://gist.github.com/ANDPPOLI/757116ed8945385b5695ac401d301ffd